# How can I mount an external USB drive in a docker container?

Tags: mount, docker

I created a Ubuntu container with this command

`docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/bash" ubuntu:latest`

I can't seem to mount an external USB drive. This works under the host machine, so no issue with the drive. When I try it in the container, I get

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb
mount: /mnt/usb: permission denied.

root@048939b7b3e3:/# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb
mount: /mnt/usb: permission denied.
```

I wouldn't know why I don't have the permissions to mount. According to this tutorial, it should work just like on the host system.

https://docs.sevenbridges.com/docs/mount-a-usb-drive-in-a-docker-container

Comment: Is it an unprivileged docker instance?

Comment: Yes, I just checked it. Haven't tried mounting again, but I am pretty sure that this is the reason for it. Thank you!